# Merge two dataframes while taking dates into account

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have two dataframes that I need to merge. The first table contains multiple rows of the same ID, but they each have their own time stamp. The second table also has those same ID's, but they each also have their own timestamps.

FIRST TABLE:

| ID | Date | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2/1/2021 | asdfadsf |
| 1 | 5/1/2021 | asdfasf |
| 1 | 7/1/2021 | freafasf |
| 2 | 4/1/2021 | afaertafa |
| 2 | 6/1/2021 | vadfgasa |
| 3 | 3/1/2021 | vadsgvadv |
| 3 | 8/1/2021 | cafdsfafa |
| 4 | 5/1/2021 | aewrqafdg |

SECOND TABLE:

| ID | Date | Num Sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/18/2020 | 1 |
| 1 | 1/15/2021 | 3 |
| 1 | 3/23/2021 | 13 |
| 1 | 4/15/2021 | 5 |
| 1 | 4/28/2021 | 32 |
| 1 | 5/10/2021 | 6 |
| 1 | 6/15/2021 | 3 |
| 2 | 2/1/2021 | 3 |
| 2 | 3/1/2021 | 5 |
| 2 | 3/15/2021 | 6 |
| 2 | 5/12/2021 | 13 |
| 2 | 5/11/2021 | 2 |
| 2 | 5/21/2021 | 32 |
| 3 | 1/1/2021 | 14 |
| 3 | 2/1/2021 | 5 |
| 3 | 4/1/2021 | 23 |
| 3 | 5/1/2021 | 54 |
| 4 | 2/1/2021 | 12 |
| 4 | 3/1/2021 | 6 |
| 4 | 4/1/2021 | 23 |

The goal is to perform a left join on the ID were the Num Sold before the date on the first table is summed and added as a column. So ID "1" for Date "2/1/2021" from the first table would take the sum of all the ID "1" Num Sold on the second table that happened on or before "2/1/2021". So the output for this would be 4. For ID "1" for Date "5/1/2021" on the first table would take the sum of all the ID "1" Num Sold on the second table that happened on or before "2/1/2021". The output of this would be 54.

The output dataframe would look like this.

| ID | Date | Description | Num Sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2/1/2021 | asdfadsf | 4 |
| 1 | 5/1/2021 | asdfasf | 54 |
| 1 | 7/1/2021 | freafasf | 63 |
| 2 | 4/1/2021 | afaertafa | 14 |
| 2 | 6/1/2021 | vadfgasa | 61 |
| 3 | 3/1/2021 | vadsgvadv | 19 |
| 3 | 8/1/2021 | cafdsfafa | 96 |
| 4 | 5/1/2021 | aewrqafdg | 41 |

Comment: I assumed by `dataframe` you meant a `pandas` dataframe, if that was an incorrect assumption please update the tags accordingly.

Comment: Yes I mean pandas dateframe. Thanks!

Comment: kindly post the expected output data frame

Comment: It has been updated @sammywemmy

Comment: it's a bit confusing, what's the date format for both tables? `d-m-y` or `m-d-y`? the second table looks like a `month-day-year` format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_sold(id,date):
    return df2[(df2['ID']==id) & (df2['Date'].le(date))]['Num Sold'].sum()

for i,v in df1.iterrows():
    df1.loc[i,'Total Sold'] = get_sold(v.ID,v.Date)
```

[image]